# jQuery AJAX call to Java RESTful web service is not working

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery AJAX to call a Java RESTful web service. Both AJAX call and RESTful are residing in my local machine. I am not able to get the response.

Here is the code which I used:

**JSP:**

```
$("#someCode").blur(function(){ 
  $.support.cors=true;
  var serviceAddress = '192.168.254.25:8080/WeightsAndMeasure/restful/sample/test';

$.ajax({
         type: 'GET',
         dataType: 'html',
         url: serviceAddress,
         crossDomain: true,
         cache:false,
         async:false,

         success: function (data) {
             alert("Data loaded: " + data);
         },
         error: function (xhr) {
             alert(xhr.responseText+' 'xhr.status+' '+ xhr.statusText);
         }
  });
});
```

**Restful:**

```
@Path("/sample")
public class SampleService 
{

  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  @Path("/test")
  public Response testService()
  {
    System.out.println("Inside testService");
return Response.ok("You got success.").header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin",  "*").build();     
  }
}
```

When I am trying it through browser URL, it is working fine. But when I am using AJAX call by `blur(function())`, it is not working.

How to call the restful and get the response successfully?

Comment: cleanup your code please

Comment: Improve the way you have posted this question.

Comment: Could be because of Same Origin Policy violation check your browser console

Comment: what is the address of the webpage which made this request

Comment: @Hi nagendra , did you find the solution for this. I have the same problems and i am not getting any further step.Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you enable CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing Filter) on your project?
As I know, you must enable it if you want to access the web service from external "requester"

Answer (score 0):

```
var serviceAddress = '192.168.254.25:8080/WeightsAndMeasure/restful/sample/test';
```

is wrong. You have to set "localhost/ajax/".

Try this in your script and control your restfull code is in "/restful/sample/test"

```
var serviceAddress = '/restful/sample/test';
```